# Incompatible pointer to integer conversion

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Im learning Objective-C and im having some problems with a project.
I made a class with a method to create a new object and im having some issues trying to create a new Object, i dont know what is the best kind of proporties in this case.

Class.h

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ObrasData : NSObject

@property (strong) NSNumber *ID;
@property (assign) char presupuesto;
@property (assign) char descripcion;
@property (assign) char aasm_state;
@property (assign) char clienteID;

- (id)initWithID:(NSNumber*)ID presupuesto:(char)presupuesto description:(char)description aasm_state:(char)aasm_state clienteID:(char)clienteID;

@end
```

Class.m

```
@implementation ObrasData

@synthesize ID = _ID;
@synthesize presupuesto = _presupuesto;
@synthesize descripcion = _descripcion;
@synthesize aasm_state = _aasm_state;
@synthesize clienteID = _clienteID;

- (id)initWithID:(NSNumber *)ID presupuesto:(char)presupuesto description:(char)description aasm_state:(char)aasm_state clienteID:(char)clienteID{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.ID = ID;
        self.presupuesto = presupuesto;
        self.descripcion = description;
        self.aasm_state = aasm_state;
        self.clienteID = clienteID;
    }
    return self;
}
```

And here im having the error: "Incompatible pointer to integer conversion"

```
 ObrasData *obra1 = [[ObrasData alloc] initWithID:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] presupuesto:100 description:@"obra de prueba" aasm_state:@"En proceso" clienteID:@"dm2"];
```

What im doing wrong? I want to show later the object on a listview

Comment: Use as a "NSString" property instead of "char"

Comment: You are passing `string` and `integer` value as parameter while your function only accepts `char` and `NSString` type value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class.h

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ObrasData : NSObject

@property (strong) NSNumber *ID;
@property (strong) NSString *presupuesto;
@property (strong) NSString *descripcion;
@property (strong) NSString *aasm_state;
@property (strong) NSString *clienteID;

- (id)initWithID:(NSNumber*)ID presupuesto:(NSString *)presupuesto description:(NSString *)description aasm_state:(NSString *)aasm_state clienteID:(NSString *)clienteID;

@end
```

Class.m

```
@implementation ObrasData

@synthesize ID = _ID;
@synthesize presupuesto = _presupuesto;
@synthesize descripcion = _descripcion;
@synthesize aasm_state = _aasm_state;
@synthesize clienteID = _clienteID;

- (id)initWithID:(NSNumber *)ID presupuesto:(NSString *)presupuesto description:(NSString *)description aasm_state:(NSString *)aasm_state clienteID:(NSString *)clienteID{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.ID = ID;
        self.presupuesto = presupuesto;
        self.descripcion = description;
        self.aasm_state = aasm_state;
        self.clienteID = clienteID;
    }
    return self;
}
```

and call like this :
 ObrasData *obra1 = [[ObrasData alloc] initWithID:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] presupuesto:@"100" description:@"obra de prueba" aasm_state:@"En proceso" clienteID:@"dm2"];

Comment: The string properties should probably be declared as `strong` or better `copy`, and not `assign`.

Comment: use NSMutableArray and init using alloc and addObject if you need to add at runtime otherwise directly initialize and more depends on memory optization and all.

Answer (score 0):

In initWithID method second parameter input type is char but you are passing integer 100.

[[ObrasData alloc] initWithID:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] **presupuesto:100** description:@"obra de prueba" aasm_state:@"En proceso" clienteID:@"dm2"];

change **presupuesto to Char**