# How to send data from MasterView to DetailView

Tags: objective-c, detailview

In my application, im showing a list of objects on a UIListView. (MasterViewController.m)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    ObrasData *obra = [self.arrObras objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = obra.descripcion;
    return cell;
}
```

Im trying to show all the data from the object, in this case, im only loading one field to test the app. (DetailViewController.m)

```
- (void)configureView
{
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.

    if (self.detailItem) {
        self.NombreObra.text = [self.detailItem description];
    }
}
```

When im going to the the DetailView, i got the following text in the label ->

```
<ObrasData: 0x892b4b0>
```

So, what is the best way to load all the data from the object? Here is where i load the array:

```
   ObrasData *obra1 = [[ObrasData alloc] initWithID:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] presupuesto:@"100" description:@"obra de prueba" aasm_state:@"En proceso" clienteID:@"dm2"];

    NSMutableArray *arrObras = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:obra1, nil];
    UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *) self.window.rootViewController;
    MasterViewController *masterController = [navController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    masterController.arrObras = arrObras;
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean 'load all the data from the object'? Load it where? You want to add the numbers and strings in your `detailItem` onto the screen? Create some UI and access the properties of `ObrasData`.

Comment: I already create a UITextView, the issue is text is showing: ObrasData: 0x892b4b0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"description" is a method on NSObject that returns a textual description of an object, and what you're seeing is the default implementation (which just prints the address).

That implies that you don't have a method implemented that overrrides "description" to returns something else.

Without seeing what ObrasData's implementation looks like, it's hard to guide you more.

Edit, having seen the implementation I see that you have a property called "descripcion" (in Spanish) that you initialise in the init method. I assume then that you actually want to do this:

```
[self.detailItem descripcion]
```

If, on the other hand you really do want to describe the whole object then you need to override the description method e.g.

```
- (NSString *)description
{
  return [NSString <create your description yourself here>];
}
```

Comment: In this question im showing the implementation: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445190/incompatible-pointer-to-integer-conversion-xcode-show-object-on-a-listvew/19445374?noredirect=1#19445374), thanks